# R Matrix Multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, state-space

I have a List, R=

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  100    0
[2,]    0  100

[[2]]
             [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.0006364031  0.2521204
[2,] 0.2521204236 99.9993643`
```

I'm suppose to do `F %*% R`

```
         F
[1,] 1 -6.264917e-04
[2,] 1  1.575666e-04
```

As in `F[1,]` matrix multiplied with `R[[1]]`, `F[2,]` matrix multiplied with `R[[2]]`

How should i go bout doing that?

Sorry. I think I was misunderstood. What I really want is `F[1,]%*%R[[1]]%*%t(F[1,])` and `F[2,]%*%R[[2]]%*%t(F[2,])`  @Sven Hohenstein

Comment: I have upvoted your answer there.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the answer. If I wanna do F %*% R %*% t(F) instead, is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: Please don't kill kittens! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370947/store-or-print-results-for-t-test-in-for-loop-r#comment21720500_15370947

Comment: Sorry. I think I was misunderstood. What I really want is         F[1,]%*%R[[1]]%*%t(F[1,]) and     F[2,]%*%R[[2]]%*%t(F[2,])

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein Sorry. I think I was misunderstood. What I really want is F[1,]%*%R[[1]]%*%t(F[1,]) and F[2,]%*%R[[2]]%*%t(F[2,])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mapply("%*%", as.data.frame(t(F)), R, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

$V1
     [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  100 -0.06264917

$V2
             [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.0006761289 0.267877
```

---

**Update**

To answer your second question:

```
lapply(R, function(x) F %*% x %*% t(F))

[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 100.00004  99.99999
[2,]  99.99999 100.00000

[[2]]
             [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 0.0003597493 0.0005083061
[2,] 0.0005083062 0.0007183373
```

---

**Update**

To answer your updated question:

```
mapply(function(x, y) y %*% x %*% as.matrix(y), R, as.data.frame(t(F)), 
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]  100

[[2]]
             [,1]
[1,] 0.0007183373
```

Comment: Do you think `Reduce` could be used here somehow? I always wonder for a solution with `Reduce` when it comes to matrix mul/add..

Comment: @Arun I suppose it's not possible with `Reduce` because the OP wants to multiply two matrices only. `Reduce` could be helpful if more than two arguments for the same operator should be used.

Comment: I see... thank you. When am I ever going to understand `Reduce`? :)

Comment: Nice solution, iterating over columns of the data frame to get rows of F.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the answer. If I wanna do F %*% R %*% t(F) instead, is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: @ Sven Sorry. I think I was misunderstood. What I really want is F[1,]%*%R[[1]]%*%t(F[1,]) and F[2,]%*%R[[2]]%*%t(F[2,])

Comment: @ShinjiOno See the new update. Hopefully, this is the right solution.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

```
R <- list(matrix(c(100,0,0,100), 2), matrix(c(0.0006364031,0.2521204236,0.2521204,99.9993643), 2))
F <- matrix(c(1, 1, -6.264917e-04,  1.575666e-04), 2)

lapply(1:2, function(x) F[x,] %*% R[[x]])
## [[1]]
##      [,1]        [,2]
## [1,]  100 -0.06264917
## 
## [[2]]
##              [,1]     [,2]
## [1,] 0.0006761289 0.267877
```

Comment: oh wow.. a small comment would've been more appropriate, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Just by doing it:

```
> F[1,]%*%R[[1]]
     [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  100 -0.06264917


> F[2,]%*%R[[2]]
             [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.0006761289 0.267877
```

Was there some particular way you wanted those stored?

Comment: What if the list is long eg. R[[1]] to R[[100]] and i wan to do it in one command?

Comment: and I wanna do F %*% R %*% t(F) instead

Comment: *What if the list is long eg. R[[1]] to R[[100]] and i wan to do it in one command?*  –- this question is already answered in response to your SO post.

Comment: > *and I wanna do F %*% R %*% t(F) instead?*  

Then I suggest you edit your stackoverflow question to add that, or post a new question over there. Don't post the same question to both places.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new. Will not double post in the future. Thanks for the  fast response